# App Crashes on Scroll UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

Application crash on component change when scroll another component for UIpickerview.

MutableArray one for height in meter's and another for feet' ft Inch.
Both Counts do have different counts meter 200 count. 
Feet array count 99.

First component do have two measurement units Feet & Meter, based on the selection  I am showing respective array. in count

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (pickerView == self.heightPickerView  && component == 0)
            return [self.heightTypeArray count];
    else if (pickerView == self.heightPickerView  && component == 1){

        if ([self.heightPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] == 0)
            return    [self.meterListArray count];

        else if ([self.heightPickerView  selectedRowInComponent:0] == 1)
            return      [self.feetInchListArray count];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Crash at return   [self.feetInchListArray objectAtIndex:row];
Since array out of bounds.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if (component == 0) {
        return [self.heightTypeArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    else if (pickerView == self.heightPickerView  && component == 1){

        if ([self.heightPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] == 0)
           return   [self.meterListArray objectAtIndex:row];

        else if (pickerView == self.heightPickerView && [self.heightPickerView  selectedRowInComponent:0] == 1){

              return   [self.feetInchListArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
```

Crash Log:
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 114 beyond bounds [0 .. 98]'
*** First throw call stack:

Can any one Advice how to resolve the issue with scroll one picker component and immediately scroll another component application crash.

Is there any method that does not allow to scroll component until another component completed scrolling.

Comment: Your array's index ends at 98, you are trying to reach index 114..

Answer (score 0):

NSRangeException that mean you are trying to access the index of some array beyond its limit.
please check your array again and datasource method again

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView